# Publishing Website to Google Cloud VM brings out multiple types error

Tags: visual-studio, google-cloud-platform

when I am publishing my website by Visual Studio 2017, I am having the error:

> Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'. This
>   can happen if the route that services this request
>   ('{controller}/{action}/{id}') does not specify namespaces to search
>   for a controller that matches the request.  If this is the case,
>   register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method
>   that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.

Additionally, I do understand that the mistake is that I have first uploaded a project with a specific name, and then uploaded another project with a different name. This has caused conflict.

How am I able to access the VM to remove the project so it won't just duplicate?

I also removed everything from the bin folder of the projects before publishing but problem still persists.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I do not have enough reputation to make a question but, when you say "uploaded" what you mean is deploy in Google Cloud App Engine Standard, in Google Cloud App Engine Flexible or what exactly do you mean?

When you say that you removed everything from the bin folder, where do you mean you did that? In local? I understand you did not do that on the Google Cloud VM.

About a deployed project, you can not access the VM where it is running since it is just an instance that can be deleted or duplicated lots of times from an image and your changes will have no effect in the next ones machines.